# php 5.5.38 advented in cpp

Tags: php, c++, apache, server

i found a good tut.: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/20/3/0/first-step

```
sudo -s ENTER
./ext_skel --extame=hello
```

I have modified the file:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(hello, whether to enable hello support,
   dnl Make sure that the comment is aligned:
   [  --enable-hello           Enable hello support])


./buildconf --force ENTER

./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --with-apxs2 --disable-cgi --enable-cli --without-pear --disable-xml --without-mysql --enable-hello    ENTER

make ENTER
make install ENTER
```

My Computer:

```
root@DELL:~/Downloads/php-5.5.38# php -f ext/hello/hello.php
Functions available in the test extension:
confirm_hello_compiled

Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
root@DELL:~/Downloads/php-5.5.38#
```

According to the tutorial it should look like this:

```
debian php-5.0.1$ php -f ext/hello/hello.php
Functions available in the test extension:<br>
confirm_hello_compiled<br>
<br>
Congratulations! You have successfully modified ext/hello/config.m4.
Module hello is now compiled into PHP.
```

Comment: There's no question in here.

Comment: Not everyone understands "Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)". English bitte!

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: My Computert: Memory access error (memory dumped)

Comment: Totorial:Congratulations! You have successfully modified ext/hello/config.m4.
Module hello is now compiled into PHP.